# If a select box put in the pop up box, it do not post?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

This is where i put a popup box into

```
echo "<tr><td>".$set['Name']."</td><td>".$set['Position']."</td><td><select name='aaa'><option value='default'>Not Share</option><option value='read'>Read Only</option><option value='edit'>Editable</option></select></td></tr>";
```

I retrieve it like `$rights=$_POST['aaa'];` and i check it has not post my item , other than the select box every thing success, and i found that not only select box , any type of the input e.g. text box also not post. Why it does not work  ? thanks .

```
<?
include("../connection/conn.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

$rights=$_POST['aaa'];


}else{?>


<html>
<head>


<script src="../plugin/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addlist").validate();
});

function popup()
{$('#win').window('open');}   //<-- call popup 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="addlist" method="post" action="add.php" >

 <a href="javascript:popup()"> Permission Settings</a>

<div id="win" class="easyui-window" closed="true" title="Login" style="width:400px;height:600px;"> //<==popup box in <div> element

<?


<select name='aaa'><option value='default'>Not Share</option><option value='read'>Read Only</option><option value='edit'>Editable</option></select> //<-- even not in the table , still not works.
<table width="100%" id="viewSub" border="1px;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th field="col1" width="40%">Name:</th>
<th field="col2" width="40%">Position:</th>
<th field="col2" width="20%">Permission:</th>
</tr>

<?
foreach ($result as $set) 
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$set['Name']."</td><td>".$set['Position']."</td><td>ss</td></tr>";

}
//".$set['UserID']."
?>
</table>


<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>


</form>

</body>

</html>

<?
}
?>
```

Comment: your popup box should be out of `<form></form>` tag

Comment: thanks i check it again and it is in the form
<form id="addlist" method="post" action="add.php" > ...</form> so i still can't figure out the problem

Comment: it post without the pop out, i have checked too

Comment: how many select fields appear on the HTML page ? because its in a loop

Comment: i mean when you open popup your popup plugin should move your div to outside of form.

Comment: What happens if you move the select box outside of the table?  Will it post then?  What happens if you give the select box an "id" attribute instead of just "name"? Please post the code for your entire form.

Comment: format your code better, that's very difficult to read.  my guess is your "popup" is plucking the `<div id="win">` your attaching it to and re-attaching it to the body.  I am not familiar with the `.window()` plugin, but that is how most dialogs and modals work.. hope that helps -

Comment: @ManseUK , now that is only 1 for test

Comment: @CFL_Jeff , When that select box outside the table, it does not post either. Sorry , How can i retrieve it using $_POST if i use id instead of name ?

Comment: @Yorgo,ckozl, You two idea is similar , that means the plugin make my select box outside the form? But how to 'pull it back' to the form? Thank you.

Comment: I have edit the post. I comment  the lines to indicate where is the popup box and where is the select box

Comment: I have deleted most of the unreleated code , thank you

Comment: Please delete more unnecessary code, like the CSS stuff...

Comment: okay as simple as it can, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your select-box:

```
<form action="your-page.php" method="post">
<!-- YOUR POPUP BOX CODE -->

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Your `<input>` and your `<select>` **MUST BE** inside a `<form>` element!

*The `<input type="submit">` is optional because you're using JQuery.*

Comment: that means there is a form inside another form?

Answer (score 0):

just move the form tag inside the `win` div

```
<script>
    $("#win").window().appendTo($("#addlist"));

</script>
<form id="addlist" method="post" action="add.php" >
<div id="win" class="easyui-window" closed="true" title="Login" style="width:400px;height:600px;">  element

     //<==popup box in


<div>

</form>
```

Comment: but there is some input field outside the popup "win" div

Comment: eg. before <div id = "win"> , there is a <input type="text">

Comment: i edit the code. Then you have to append the div back to form after call .window() function.

Comment: ' you have to append the div back' , would you mind explain it more further ? thank you.
simply speaking, first i have to add $("#win").window().appendTo($("#addlist")); between <head>
and what is the next step?

Comment: That is close to the answer. that means, when should i call window function ? And after call the function, how can i append the div back?